# Lucene wildcard startwith or equal

Tags: java, lucene, wildcard

Searching for `'car*'` I'd like to find `'cars'` and `'car'`. Actualy `'car'` is not found, I'think because `'car'` does not start with `'car'` but is the same word.

The workaround I found is to find `'car OR car*'`, are there better ways to do that?

Here is the code (actually `'car'` was an example, the real word I'm looking for is `'epatite'`):

```java
final QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("fullText", new StandardAnalyzer());
final IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
final IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
Query q1 = queryParser.parse("epatite*");
Query q2 = queryParser.parse("epatite");
System.out.println("epatite*:"+searcher.search(q1, maxResult).scoreDocs.length);
System.out.println("epatite:"+searcher.search(q2, maxResult).scoreDocs.length);
```

and here the result

```
epatite*:0
epatite:46
```

The index is created with this code:

```java
final IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
Directory tmpindex = FSDirectory.open(indexFolder);
final IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(tmpindex, config);
final List<String> icd10List = getStringToIndex()

for(String icd10 : icd10List){
    final Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("fullText", icd10, Field.Store.YES));
    w.addDocument(doc);
}

w.close();
```

The strings that are indexed are like those:

- B15.-: Epatite virale acuta A
- B15.0: Epatite virale A con coma epatico
- B15.9: Epatite virale A senza coma epatico
- B16.-: Epatite virale acuta B
- ...

Comment: `'car*'` is translated as a `PrefixQuery`, and  should also find `'car'`. Can you add your code?

Comment: As @YossiVainshtein said, I would normally expect this to work. Perhaps something in your analyzer is affecting "car" but not "cars".

Comment: could you share the code, how you indexed docs?